# Jquery ui tabs in iframe in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, jquery-ui-tabs

At first, sorry for my poor English.
My problem is: a have site1.com and site2.com.
In the site1.com i append this html:

```
<iframe src="site2.com">
```

in site2.com i use jquery ui.tabs. There are 5 tabs in site2.com
and i initialize tabs in site2.com by this code:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({});
```

And this works everywhere except IE. In IE i see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r338.png , but when I click on the other tabs, nothing happens.

How can i fix this?

Comment: can you paste the `site2.com's` head section or full html?

Comment: In site2.com there are many-many-many *.js files, *.css files and meta tags... You can see example of problem there: http://www.hpfc.org/pages.asp?pageid=72984 In ie tabs not working... Hope for your help...

Comment: there are some javascript errors on the page and ie don't manage it while other brosers(modern) manages it to render.

Comment: But if open iframe src in new tab - it works!!!